# Pyodbc - determine if any transaction is pending and needs to be commited

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc

I'm working with pyodbc with 'autocommit' set to false. 
I assume that if only `SELECT` sql statements are used (no `INSERT` or `UPDATE`) then a call to 'commit' function would do nothing with the DB.

Is there any way in pyodbc to determine if there is any changes pending that would be lost if I don't call 'commit'?

I have been thinking to use pyodbc 'getinfo' function which is a wrapper over SQLGetInfo, but can't find any suitable parameter for it.

Actually what I want to do is just notify a user that data in the DB are going to be changed, but I don't want to control what SQL statements have been used (only `SELECT` or also `UPDATE` & `INSERT`) because there are too many places where I would need to check it.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, pyodbc has not a build-in function to check pending commits.

In SQL Server (starting with 2008) you can check pending commits at database level by using the `database_transaction_state` field in `sys.dm_tran_database_transactions` table.  The transaction's state with pending commit is expected to be `4`. While one without pending commit is expected to be `3`.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-tran-database-transactions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), the mentioned states are defined as:

> 3 = The transaction has been initialized but has not generated any log
>   records.
>
> 4 = The transaction has generated log records.

The following script checks this idea.

**Output**

```
Starting point, no pending transaction or commits
    @@TRANCOUNT = 0
    database_transaction_state = None
Disable autocommit
    @@TRANCOUNT = 1
    database_transaction_state = 3
Perform an Insert
    @@TRANCOUNT = 1
    database_transaction_state = 4
Explicit commit
    @@TRANCOUNT = 1
    database_transaction_state = 3
Enable autocommit
    @@TRANCOUNT = 0
    database_transaction_state = None
```

**Code**

```
import pyodbc

conn_param = {
    "DRIVER": "{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}",
    "SERVER": "(localdb)\\ProjectsV13",
    "DATABASE": "master"
}

conn_string = ";".join(["{}={}".format(k, v) for k, v in conn_param.items()])

conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_string, autocommit=True)
cursor = conn.cursor()


def check():
    print("\t@@TRANCOUNT = {}".format(
        cursor.execute("select @@TRANCOUNT").fetchval()
    ))

    print("\tdatabase_transaction_state = {}".format(
        cursor.execute("""
        select database_transaction_state
        from sys.dm_tran_database_transactions 
        where transaction_id = CURRENT_TRANSACTION_ID() 
        and database_id = (
            select dbid from sys.sysprocesses where spid = @@SPID
        )""").fetchval()
    ))


cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS testTable")
cursor.execute("SELECT * INTO testTable FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) as x(a)")

print("Starting point, no pending transaction or commits")
check()

print("Disable autocommit")
conn.autocommit = False
check()

print("Perform an Insert")
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO testTable VALUES (4)")
check()

print("Explicit commit")
conn.commit()
check()

print("Enable autocommit")
conn.autocommit = True
check()

cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS testTable")
cursor.close()
conn.close()
```